# Is it possible to create text animation in PowerPoint 2007(or 2010) like in Keynote?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

Is it possible to create text animation in PowerPoint 2007(or 2010) like in Keynote?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: You can create text animations in PowerPoint, but what effect are you trying to duplicate? Can you update your question with a little bit more information?

Comment: if you want an answer make effort in your questions first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going with no. PowerPoint does not feature the same transitions as Keynote, and you cannot recreate them.

Answer (score 2):

You sure can create text animations in PowerPoint! It's pretty easy feature. But I'm not sure what exact ones you are trying to duplicate from Keynote. Is there a specific type you're looking for?